# How to restrict the Visibility of RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1 folder in IOS while accessing downloaded files in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

It happens while I allow user to see Documents Directory to access Downloaded files.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your relevant code?